# can I use contains to match the value of an objects property?

Tags: windows, powershell

I can use contains like this:

```
myArr= 'aaa','bbb','ccc'
myArr -contains 'aaa'
```

But can I use it on an array of objects? Say I have an array of objects and I want to know if one of their 'someProp' property equals some value?

This doesn't work but I'd like to do something like this

```
myArr = #an array of objects
myArr -contains @{someProp = 'hasThisValue'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't with that syntax, but you could using slightly different syntax:

```
$myarr.someprop -contains 'hasthisvalue'
```

Using a property of a collection, PowerShell creates a collection of property values, so -contains works like you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question.
I'd say the `Compare-Object` cmdlet would be the one to use.

I did some tests on my end and it appears that `-contains` will work as intended for objects if you have a reference to the object. If you try to use contains with an identical object  which is not a reference, then it will fails.

Take this example for instance.

```
$myArr = @(@{'Item 1'='Value 1'},@{'Item 2'='Value 2'},@{})
$ItemByVal= @{'Item 1'='Value 1'}
$ItemByRef = $myArr | select -First 1

Write-host "Compare using Contains by val: $($myArr -contains $UtemByVal)" -ForegroundColor Red
Write-Host "Comapre using contains By ref: $($myArr -contains $ItemByRef)" -ForegroundColor Green
```

`ItemByVal` won't work using contains.

The `Compare-Object` cmdlet does work fine though using both method. You could use it by reference or by value.

```
Compare-Object $myArr $ItemByVal -ExcludeDifferent -IncludeEqual -PassThru
Compare-Object $myArr $ItemByRef -ExcludeDifferent -IncludeEqual -PassThru
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

You must use property like explain @Mike Shepard.
You can use -in too like this :

```
$myArr = @{PropName1='Value 1';PropName2='test1'},@{PropName1='Value 2';PropName2='test2'}
"Value 1" -in $myArr.PropName1
```